# C++: Convert unsigned long long int into vector<char> and vice versa

Tags: c++, syntax, vector, integer, long-integer

Can anyone tell me how to convert unsigned long long int into vector and vice versa.

For converting from unsigned long long int to vector, I tried the following:

```
unsigned long long int x;
vector<char> buf(sizeof(x));
memcpy( &buf[0], &x, sizeof( x ) );
```

When I tested for x = 1234567890, it failed. But when I tried it for smaller values of x (say 1-100), it works...

For converting vector to unsigned long long int, I used:

```
   unsigned long long int =  (unsigned long long int)buf[0];
```

Can anyone tell me how to do it.

Comment: yes, I am trying to split the integer into a vector<char> so that i can send it from the client to the server and read it back.

Comment: If you want to do that, you should probably consider combining Mark B's solution into template functions which can write/read any sized type into your vector<char> safely.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just remember that copying bytes around won't be cross-platform portable. Your memcpy looks fine, so why not re-create that on the way back out? What you've written simply takes the first byte of the vector and converts it to an `unsigned long long` which explains why it works for small numbers.

Try this instead to get the value back out of the vector:

```
unsigned long long int x;
memcpy(&x, &buf[0], sizeof(x));
```

Comment: Hehe, and if you tried his current approach on a big endian system  buf[0] would only contain anything if you had a really big value of x.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of `memcpy`ing directly into the vector you can use `std::vector::assign` to perform the copying.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  unsigned long long int x = 0x0807060504030201;
  std::vector<char> v;

  v.assign( reinterpret_cast<char *>( &x ), reinterpret_cast<char *>( &x ) + sizeof( x ) );

  for( auto i = v.begin(); i != v.end(); ++i ) {
    std::cout << std::hex << static_cast<int>( *i ) << ' ';
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;

  // To convert back
  auto y = *reinterpret_cast<unsigned long long int *>( &v[0] );
  std::cout << "y = " << std::hex << std::showbase << y << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
y = 0x807060504030201
```

Comment: How to save it in reversed order, I mean the output of printing will be 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1?

Comment: @cygi1989 Use [`std::reverse`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse). After `v.assign(...);` add `std::reverse(v.begin(), v.end());`

Comment: Great. Is it possible to assign it smallest possible vector, let's say I have a function which return the smalles number of bytes necessary to store given integer. How would I do it?

Comment: @cygi1989 I'm not sure what you're asking. Why don't you post another question?

Answer (score 3):

You have to change your last line:

```
memcpy( &buf[0], reinterpret_cast<char*>(&x), sizeof( x ) );
```

**Edit** I was talking nonsense, that line is fine the way it is, but your conversion back is bad - you convert the value, instead of the pointer:

```
unsigned long long int val = *reinterpret_cast<unsigned long long int*>(&buf[0]);
```

Comment: @MarkB: I realized that too - was confused there for a moment.